# Save a list to a file

Tags: python, file, list, save

I have a library where I want to create a new book and then add it to my list of books. 
What I have problems with is to save the file between calls.

This is how I read the file:

```
def read_bookfile():

    try:
        booklibrary_file = open("a.txt")

        booklibrary_list = []
        booklist = booklibrary_file.readlines()
        for rad in booklist:
            linelist = rad.split("/")
            title = linelist[0]
            firstname = linelist[1]
            lastname = linelist[2]
            isbn = int(linelist[3])
            availability = linelist[4]
            borrowed = linelist[5]
            late = linelist[6]
            returnday = linelist[7]
            b = Book(title, firstname, lastname, isbn, availability, borrowed, late, returnday) 
            booklibrary_list.append(b)
        booklibrary_file.close()
        return booklibrary_list
```

Now I want to know how to save to my file.

Comment: Have you considered using a Database and/or ORM for handling this?

Comment: why the `try:` block with no `except`?

Comment: As @AaronCroyle mentioned, it might be best to not use a text file to store this data. Consider reading up on [SQLite](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) as an introduction to persistent data storage.

Answer (score 7):

In order to save to a file, you have to open it in Write-Append mode.

```
library_file = open("a.txt", "a")
...
library_file.write("Some string\n")
...
library_file.close()
```

Refer to Python's documentation on [Built-in Functions](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

First off, here's an easier way to read, assuming those eight fields are the only ones:

```
def read_bookfile(filename="a.txt"):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return [Book(*line.split('/')) for line in f]
```

Now, to save:

```
 def save_bookfile(booklist, filename='a.txt'):
     with open(filename, 'w') as f:
         for book in booklist:
             f.write('/'.join([book.title, book.firstname, book.lastname, str(book.isbn),
                               book.availability, book.borrowed, book.late, book.returnday])
                     + '\n')
```

assuming the `Book` model just saves those attributes in as they were passed (as strings).

Explanations:

- The `with` statement opens your file and makes sure that it gets closed when control passes out of the statement, even if there's an exception or something like that.
- Passing in the filename as an argument is preferable, because it allows you to use different filenames without changing the function; this uses a default argument so you can still call it in the same way.
- The `[... for line in f]` is a list comprehension, which is like doing `lst = []; for line in f: lst.append(...)` but faster to write and to run.
- Opening a file in `'w'` mode allows you to write to it. Note that this will delete the already-existing contents of the file; you can use `'a'` or `'w+'` to avoid that, but that requires a little more work to reconcile the existing contents with your book list.
- The `*` in `read_bookfile` splits a list up as if you passed them as separate arguments to a function.
- `'/'.join()` takes the list of strings and joins them together using slashes: `'/'.join(["a", "b", "c"])` is `"a/b/c"`. It needs strings, though, which is why I did `str(isbn)` (because `book.isbn` is an int).

Answer (score 1):

Python is "batteries included", remember?

Consider using the "csv" module:

```
use csv

csv.reader(...)
csv.writer(...)
```

I think these have lots of options (like you can set your delimiters to be other than commas; you can read in to a list of dictionaries, etc.)

See [Python Docs for CSV reader/writer](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html):

Answer (score 0):

I have to make a few assumptions about your Book class, but I think this might help put you on the right track:

```
bookList = read_bookfile()

outfile = open("booklist.txt", "w")

for book in bookList:
        bookStr = book.title + " " + book.firstname + " " + book.lastname + " " + book.isbn + " " + book.availability + " " + book.borrowed + " " + book.late + " " + book.returnday + "\n"
        outfile.write(bookStr)

outfile.close()
```

Comment: Be warned that opening a file in "w" mode will truncate any previous versions of the file. Source: [Python Documentation on Built-in Functions](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: um, you're passing a tuple to `write()`?

Comment: Good point... given the asker's code though, it seems as though it's more of a file formatting question than it is one about updating a catalogue of books

Comment: Oh jeez, Shep... I'm a dummy. Fixed

Comment: Note that the original file was read in split by slashes, so probably you want to join with slashes, not spaces....

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right... if the asker finds this useful, I'll let him fill in the blanks.